# How would you write an effect to rotate an image continously?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm trying to animate an Image when I send a request and then stop rotating that image when a response is received but I'm having trouble with the animation.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <s:Sequence id="requestAnimation" repeatCount="0">
        <s:Parallel>
            <s:Fade alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" target="{busyLogo}" duration="250" />
            <s:Fade alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" target="{cornerLogo}" duration="250" />
        </s:Parallel>
        <s:Sequence repeatCount="0">
            <s:Rotate3D angleZFrom="0" 
                        angleZTo="360" 
                        autoCenterProjection="true" 
                        autoCenterTransform="true" 
                        duration="1000"
                        target="{busyLogo}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Sequence>
```

The image rotates and when it gets to the end of a full rotation is slows to a stop and then starts up again. I would like it to rotate in one continuous loop.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm wondering how your busyLogo can rotate at all with this code because in the main Sequence you first fade out the alpha to 0 on busyLogo and fade in the cornerLogo. It should be the other way around - you are supposed to fade in the busyLogo and then rotate it ?

But the main problem seem to be the repeatCount="0" on the main sequence that would play the whole sequence (fadeout and rotate) indefinitely. If you remove the repeatCount="0" on the main sequence, it would fade out and then stop at the second sequence that would spin the logo indifinitely with it's repeatCount="0"

Make sure you stop both sequencies once you are done to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I noticed that after I went back to work on it. I removed the fade out and broke the animation into two separate sequences. It seems to be working (crosses fingers).

Answer (score 0):

Set the easer used on the Rotate3D effect. The default value is Sine, which is causing the slowdown and speedup. If you want to make it constant, change it to `spark.effects.easing.Linear`.

Comment: That will only cause it to play once. I would like the image to rotate indefinitely.

Comment: I misread your question, I guess. My answer above has been corrected.

Comment: Thanks I added the Linear easer into the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I now have the following. This seems to work but the animation is not as smooth as I hoped. Might try doing a release build and seeing if that is better or add smoothing to the image.

```
    <s:Parallel id="requestAnimation" >
        <s:Fade alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" target="{busyLogo}" duration="250" />
        <s:Sequence suspendBackgroundProcessing="true" repeatCount="0">
            <s:Rotate3D angleZFrom="0" 
                        angleZTo="360" 
                        easer="{new Linear(0,0)}" 
                        autoCenterProjection="true" 
                        autoCenterTransform="true" 
                        duration="1000"
                        target="{busyLogo}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Parallel>


    <s:Sequence id="fadeOutRequest" effectEnd="requestAnimation.end()">
        <mx:AnimateProperty  property="alpha" fromValue="1" toValue="0" target="{busyLogo}" duration="1050" />
    </s:Sequence>

    <s:Image id="mainLogo" x="0" y="0" width="128" height="128" source="{logo256}"
             rollOver="{requestAnimation.play()}" rollOut="{fadeOutRequest.play()}"
             alpha="0"/>
    <s:BitmapImage id="logo4" x="32" y="32" source="{logo64}"/>
```